# Restful API for Neural Network Training&Prediction?

Tags: web-services, rest, neural-network

Let's say i want to send Data to a server,  then train a NN with that Data and later on want to get prediction results.

That would break Rest because the Data for a request are Not evertime the Same for every request (especially of there would bei predictions while training) right?

Is there a good Standard oft there for that or should i rather implement a custom Server?